# using dbunit with oracle. Schema problems

Tags: oracle, dbunit

How do you restrict DBunit to a specific schema. When doing DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT,
dbunit this exception

> org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: SCHEMA_UPDATE_TBL

But this table is not in the schema I am using. I think it is coming from another table in the same Oracle database. How do I limit dbunit to look at my schema.

I'm using jpa.

eg connection am using in my persistence.xml is like this

```
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="mikea"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mikea"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MOT4"/>
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.  The DatabaseConnection() constructor accepts a default schema parameter.  For example, "mikea" is the schema I want to use:

```
connection = new DatabaseConnection(
        ( ( HibernateEntityManager ) em ).getSession().connection(),"mikea" );
DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig();
Class factory_class = Class.forName( "org.dbunit.ext.oracle.Oracle10DataTypeFactory" );
config.setProperty( DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, factory_class.
                newInstance() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also answerer by DBUnit FAQ's: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AmbiguousTableNameException

> This error occurs when no schema is specified and that DbUnit detect
>   that it is getting columns information from multiple tables having the
>   same name and located in different schemas.
>
> You can solve this problem in three different ways:
>
> - Provide the schema name when creating the database connection. Note
>     that for Oracle you must specify the schema name in uppercase.
> - Ensure that the connection is restricted to access only one schema.
> - Enable the qualified table names feature.
>     http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/properties.html#qualifiedtablenames